# Hindi Marathi font on Android

Tags: android, fonts, hindi

which font is most suitable for Android application developed in Marathi/ Hindi indian language. I tried with mangal and droidsansfallback but still the words dont appear as they should. I don't see the boxes or some special characters after using above font which is good, but still the marathi/hindi words doesnt have exacts alphabets. Any help/guidance will be appreciated. Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

As Devanagari fonts are not supported by Android, you can still give that support to your Application.

For Marathi font copy font file to your asset folder. then use the following code.

```
 TextView text_view = new TextView(this);
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), MarathiFont);
 text_view.setTypeface(font);
 text_view.setText("मराठी");
```

the same way u can give support for hindi....

> Marathifont = any marathi or devanagari font

e.g

> Marathifont = "kiran.ttf"

Comment: where to get Marathifont.ttf from, that way I have used Droidsansfallback.ttf but it doesnt recognise marathi characters that well.

Answer (score 0):

Devnagari fonts are not supported in older devices. You can replace the default font after rooting the device. mangal font worked pretty well for me.

[Fontoosh](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technoguff.fontoosh) can be helpful for installing devnagari font or replacing the font.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/).
Just search for Hindi/Marathi and you will get fonts for it.
Noto Sans Devanagari is good.