# Android apps in hindi or marathi font

Tags: android, fonts, hindi

I want to develop an application in hindi/marathi font for android device? how to do that? Do I need to download devnagiri font?

Comment: You might want to check [this][1] link.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839336/hindi-marathi-font-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Hindi is natively supported from API 10 (Android 2.3) upwards.